# ASP.Net Web API 2 изменение внешней базы данных SQL на MS Azure

Tags: база-данных, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, azure

Доброго времени суток. Суть проблемы: есть приложение на Web Api, и есть SQL-база на Azure. если приложение запускается локально - проводить операции чтения и записи в базу(развернутую на сервере) получается без ошибок. Если развернуть приложение в Azure - данные из базы читаются, но при любой попытке добавить запись происходит ошибка. База данных при этом инициируется из развернутого приложения, инициирующие записи в таблицу добавляются. А после инициации - только чтение. В чем может быть проблема. и куда копать? 
P.S. База обрабатывается через Entity Framework 6

Comment: А что настроено в файрволе SQL сервера? Разрешен ли доступ для Azure Services?

Comment: в файрволе SQL сервера разрешен доступ с ip от 0.0.0.0 до 255.255.255.255, доступ к Azure Services разрешен. Приложение может читать информацию из этой базы, но не может писать

Comment: Очень странный случай. А пробовал просто создать новую базу данных и новый сервер? В моей практике было такое, когда просто пересоздание ресурса в Azrue помогало...

Comment: Пересоздание ресурсов проблему не исправило. Все так же приложение может выполнять все действия из localhost, и только читать, но не изменять базу данных после того, как было развернуто в Azure. База создана в Azure, строка подключение не меняется при переходе от localhost к развертке

Comment: А Connection String вы генерировали в самом портале или сами подбирали? Попробуйте взять сгенерированную... Может что-то не то там...

Comment: Строку пробовал и заменять, и оставлять такой же, как при локальном тестировании приложения (база все время на сервере)

Comment: Гм.... Что-то я вообще в полной расерянности. А если создать новый тестовый проект, как с ним обстоят дела? Может дело в настройках Entity Framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема была исправлена. Все дело было в ключе строки подключения. В строку подключения, которая была сгенерирована MS Azure нужно дописать параметр ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite, после этого приложение может производить и чтение, и запись.